# Как добавить в существующую структуру json(файл) новую запись?

Tags: python, json

Есть файл music.json:

```
{
    "object": [
        {
            "singer": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "first_name": "Jenifer",
                    "last_name": "Lopez"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "song": [
        {
            "executor_id": 2,
            "song_name": "Papi",
            "source_song": "https://sefon.pro/artist/2169-jenifer-lopez/",
            "repeat": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Новая запись должна записываться в главный обьект следущим образом:

```
{
    ... (существующая структура)

    "object" [
        {
            "singer": [...],
            "song": [...]
        }
    ]
}
```

тоесть первый вариант кода должен повторяться...
чтобы записать новую запись и не стереть существующие нужно открыть файл очевидно, открываю файл вот так:

```
with open("music.json", "a+") as file:
    тут тупик :-D
```

не доходит как добавить новую запись вот так:

```
{
    ...
    "object": [...]
}
```

пытаюсь через `json.load(file)` сперва получить содержимое файла и добавить вот так:

```
with open("music.json", "a+") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    data["object"][1] = to_json
    json.dump(data,file)
```

там уже ошибка...
подскажите пожалуйста как можно это сделать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
    "object": 
    ...
}
```

Это словарь и в нём есть запись с ключом `object`. Вы не можете в словарь записать ещё один ключ `object`, ключи словаря не могут повторяться. При чтении такого `json` будет либо ошибка, либо останется только один из ключей, мне лень проверять.

Вам нужно поменять структуру `json`, например, поместить всё это ещё и в список, в списке элементы могут повторяться, можно повторять, например, словари:

```
[
    {
        "object": 
        ...
    }
    {
        "object": 
        ...
    }
]
```

Ну либо вам нужно добавлять элементы в списки `object` и `song`, тогда это нужно делать так:

```
data["object"].append(new_object)
data["song"].append(new_song)
```

Ну и да, `json` нужно читать целиком, модифицировать и потом записывать целиком.

Comment: "Ну и да, json нужно читать целиком, модифицировать и потом записывать целиком." помогло! Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Если ключ уже есть в словаре. То python перезапишет на последнее.
Для понимания:

```
slov = {1: "test", 2:"test2"}
slov[3] = "test3"
print(slov)
{1: "test", 2:"test2", 3: "test3"}
```

При условии, что ключ присутствует:

```
slov[1] = "tyty"
print(slov)
{1: "tyty", 2:"test2", 3: "test3"}
```

Для добавления и формирования у одного ключа нескольких значений(это возможно),но это уже другая история.